# Logging with Guice

Tags: tomcat, guice

Does anybody know if there is a way to make Guice log errors before throwing them?  We are using Tomcat and any exceptions thrown at deploy-time keep getting swallowed.  If we could make guice log the exception before tomcat has the opportunity to throw it away we would have a much better chance of solving our current issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably your own code that calls Guice.createInjector(). Wrap that in a try/catch block and print the error to whichever log you prefer!

Comment: This works for deploy time, I think I need to figure out why Tomcat will not log exceptions when I hit my RPC servlet.